# fpga gpio pins as uart pins (tx and rx)?

Tags: fpga, uart, gpio

I am trying to use fpga de2115 and (ftdi ft232rl usb to serial)  to communicate with pc.
Can the tx/rx pins from the adapter be connected directly to the fpga gpio pins?
The board has rs232 port , but i don't have the rs232 cable and also want to avoid this.
So can i assign uart hdl assigned pins to fpga gpio and connect them to the adapter tx/rx pins?

thank you.

Comment: "de2115" is not an FPGA. Is it possible you're referring to the [Altera DE2-115 Development and Education Board](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=502) from Terasic? The actual FPGA on that board is a Cyclone EP4CE115.

Comment: The main issue would be if the IO voltage is sufficiently compatible.  IIRC some cyclone parts could not tolerate nominally 3v3 sigmals if they had any ringing on top.

Comment: amazon.com/dp/B0753HBT12

Comment: You can use it directly with General Purpose IOs, if it's a standard 3.3V cable.

Comment: yes ...the board is altera de2-115, default volt  is 3.3V  on gpios of the board.....the (usb to serial) adapter is also switchable to 3.3v.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set the correct voltage level for pins in the GPIO expansion header to 3.3V

Refer to [page 46](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/portal/dsn/42/doc-us-dsnbk-42-1404062209-de2-115-user-manual.pdf)

These pins have tolerance upto 3.7 V, hence you should be able to use your USB-TTL 3.3V cable's *rx* and *tx* directly.

Don't forget the ground connection as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer.....so i need to make at least 3-connections ....({adapter-tx} to {hdl-assigned-gpio-rx}) , ({adapter-rx} to {hdl-assigned-gpio- tx}) and ({adapter-gnd} to {fpga-labeled/dedicated-gpio-gnd})...??

Comment: That's right.................